# Does anyone have an idea how to find what or who is calling findstr.exe to run speratically?

Tags: windows-10, findstr

I have Windows 10, and about a week ago I installed Avast Device Driver Updater and it did update my chipset, intel processor, and Intel RAID drivers, which were the only ones I allowed it to with no problems. However a couple of days after I started noticing that a CMD window just pops up out of no where and seemingly when it wants to, and it runs a bunch of FINDSDR commands on a bunch of directories that I don't have on my laptop. The window then closes before I have a chance to read any of the paths and quicker then I can catch it to copy anything. The problem is that I can not find the program, shell script, or anything that would be running that might be causing this to run.

I do know that it always tries the to find the same directories, and they fail every time. But I just cant read them... I checked and according to Avast, the Driver Updater does not run any scripts like this, so it should not be the updater process, and just to be sure, I have stopped it from Auto Loading at Boot, and I turned off all it's functions in the settings.

So, I would like to know if anyone knows of any tricks that would help me identify what is calling the findstr.exe, or a way to trap it, while it's running (though even it I trapped it, I don't know how I can use that info to find the culprit that is causing it to run. I am hoping some one know how I can figure out what or where its running from and whos making it run. Any ideas? Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: I'd start with checking scheduled tasks for anything dodgy

Comment: I did I ran a virus / malware scan, I checked for any process eating up I/o, memory, CPU, or services that I didn't recognize, I checked everything that I know to check and I'll be darned if I can come up with anything :(